# Printing (Factorial of 2^n)/(2^n -1)mod m in C++

Tags: c++, factorial

How can we store and print factorial(2^n) / (2^n  -1))mod1000000009 in C++.Here n can be as large as 20. When I try to print this using the following code, it shows segmentation fault for n=20
    #include
    #include
    using namespace std;

```
long int factorial(int n)
{
if(n<=1){return 1;}
else
return (n%1000000009)*(factorial(n-1))%1000000009;

}

int main()
{

int K;
long long int numofmatches=0;
long long int denominator=0;
long long int factor=0;
long long int times=0;
long long int players=0;
cin>>K;


if(K==1)
{
    cout<<2<<endl<<2<<endl; 
    return 0;
}    
else
{
    denominator=pow(2,K);
cout<<"Denominator="<<denominator<<endl;

numofmatches=factorial(denominator)%1000000009;

denominator-=1;
cout<<"numberofmatches="<<numofmatches<<endl;
cout<<"Denominator="<<denominator<<endl;

factor=numofmatches/denominator;
cout<<"Factor="<<factor<<endl;

while(times<=denominator)
{
cout<<(times*factor)<<endl;
++times;
}

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: writing code would be a good start. Using some variables wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: Q#1: Factorial on `(2^n)/(2^n-1)` or just on `(2^n)`? Q#2: Mod on `(10^8+9)` or just on `(10^8)`?

Comment: Your question is not clear, either try to elaborate or post the code you tried with.

Comment: Done. Kindly refer to the question again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that `(2^n)! / (2^n-1)` is equal to `(2^n-2)! x 2^n`.

Now, `(2^20-2)!` by itself is already an extremely large number to calculate.

What you can do instead, is to modulo the intermediate result with 1000000009 after every multiplication:

```
#define MAX ((1<<20)-2)

unsigned long long res = 1;
for (unsigned int i=1; i<=MAX; i++)
    res = (res*i)%1000000009;
res = (res*(MAX+2))%1000000009;
```

If you want to iterate all values of `n` between 1 and 20, then you can use:

```
#define MAX_N 20

unsigned int arr[MAX_N+1] = {0};

void Func()
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    for (int n=1; n<=MAX_N; n++)
    {
        unsigned int max = (1<<n)-2;
        for (; i<=max; i++)
            res = (res*i)%1000000009;
        arr[n] = (unsigned int)((res*(max+2))%1000000009);
    }
}
```

BTW, for any `n` larger than 29 the result will simply be 0, as `(2^30-2)` is larger than 1000000009.

So `(2^30-2)!` is divisible by 1000000009, and therefore, `(2^30-2)! mod 1000000009` equals 0.

Comment: it is (2^n)-1 and not 2^(n-1)

Comment: Your first line is wrong. How can (2^n)!/((2^n)-1)be equal to     (2^(n-2))! X 2^n

Comment: @user3425724: `K! / (K-1) = 1 x 2 x ... x (K-2) x (K-1) x K`, right? Now, divide both sides by `(K-1)`, and you'll get `1 x 2 x ... x (K-2) x K`, which is equal to `(K-2)! x K`.

Comment: Thanks.. It seems that I was ridiculously confused :)

Comment: @user3425724: You're welcome. I have updated the answer with a function that calculates this value for every `n` between 1 and 20 (or any other limit that you choose). Please note that you have specified `1000000009` in your question, and if memory serves correctly, in the previous version of this question it was `10^8+9`, which is smaller ("shorter by a zero").